# CSS override is not working. Override overwritten by component CSS. How to fix?

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to remove the margin from the material-ui ExpansionPanel component when it's expanded, but can't make it work.

My code is as follows:

```
const styles = {
    expanded: {
        margin: "0px",
    }
}

const Result = props => {

    const { classes } = props;

    return (
        <ExpansionPanel
            defaultExpanded
            classes={{expanded: classes.expanded}}
        >
            <ExpansionPanelSummary>
            </ExpansionPanelSummary>
            <ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
    );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Result);
```

When I inpect the source, my override:

```
.Result-expanded-1x42rei {
    margin: 0;
}
```

is below the component css:

```
.MuiExpansionPanel-expanded-60 {
    margin: 16px 0;
}
```

Why does my override get overwritten by the component CSS?
It works if I set the css as !important, but I was told it's a "illegal" to do. How do I fix it?

Update: When I write the exact same code in codesandbox.io it works...

Update2 The reason it was not working was because I was importing withStyles from @material-ui/styles instead of @material-ui/core/styles

Answer (score 0):

I tried that too before and I did not work for me. I ended up doing the shorthand way for overriding CSS.

```
import MuiExpansionPanel from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel";

const ExpansionPanel = withStyles({
  root: {

  },
  expanded: {
    margin: 0
  }
})(MuiExpansionPanel);

const styles = {
}

const Result = props => {

    const { classes } = props;

    return (
        <ExpansionPanel
            defaultExpanded
        >
            <ExpansionPanelSummary>
            </ExpansionPanelSummary>
            <ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
    );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Result);
```

Let me know if it works!!!

Comment: Thank you for answering! I've already tried this because the example at mui website does it this way. Same thing happens. It's so weird, because when I use the exact same code in codesandbox it works just fine.

Comment: Found the reason, always some stupid mistake. I was importing withStyles from @material-ui/styles, which is considered alpha/unstable instead of importing from @material-ui/core/styles.